# Xamarin Forms - How to get the current country of the device

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there a way to detect the current country of a mobile device? What I want for my application is that on sign up page, I require my user to enter the country code and the mobile number. I want the country code to be filled up based on the current country the user is in by default on my picker control.

Comment: Try this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/. But its only for android.

Comment: You can use geolocation. But I don't know if that isn't a bit Overkill. [Geolocator plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)

Comment: If you decide to use it , I will post an answer with a few key points about using it

Comment: Use [`DependencyService` ](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/), and in Android you can use `String country= Locale.Default.Country;` to get country.

Answer (score 4):

What about `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion`?
No platform code needed!
[Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion/)

Comment: On iOS, this will return the device's language instead of the actual region.

Comment: this doesnt get the country phonenumber code

Comment: This ive wrong info! I am in Australia yet it shows UK!

Comment: You can check the RegionInfo class for different formats, and of course, this relays on the device settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo?view=net-5.0

Answer (score -1):

for Xamarin Android : Java.Util.Locale.Default.ToString()
for Xamarin IOS : NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[1]

Comment: This gives wrong value. For example I am in Australia, it shows en-GB (Great Britain)!